# how should I make a recursive rule in yacc/bison and lex?

Tags: parsing, bison, yacc, lex

I'm writing a simple HTML parser using yacc(bison) and flex.
how can I make this rule:

```
column -> <td>text</td>column | NULL
```

I've tried many forms like this:

```
COLUMN : L_TAG T_OPEN R_TAG ID L_TAG T_CLOSE R_TAG COLUMN
| 
;
```

//The tokens are specified in lex.

unfortunately it doesn't work. it gives me the shift/reduce error. whether I put the COLUMN at the beginning of the rule or at the end. whether I use the NULL like this:

```
{$$ = NULL}
```

or leave it empty.
I need the NULL thing to make the rule recursive and be able to have the same tag more than once next to each other. something like this:

```
<tr>name</tr><tr>age</tr>
```

how can I make this work?

Answer (score 2):

```
column       :/* empty */
             | column '<' TD '>' TEXT '<' '/' TD '>'
```

You can optimize your rules as far as you make it more specific. for the recursion thing you should in a lalr(1) grammar make it left recursive.

good luck

Answer (score 1):

You'd normally break it up into a number of pieces:

```
table : TABLE rows CLOSE_TABLE
      ;

rows: 
    | rows row
    ;

row:  TR row_header cells CLOSE_TR
   ;

row_header: TH text CLOSE_TH
          ;

cells: 
     | cells cell
     ;

cell: TD TEXT CLOSE_TD
    ;
```

Where `TABLE` is `<table>`, `CLOSE_TABLE` is `</table>`, and so on.

Oh, just to be clear: I haven't worked very had to ensure this really parses HTML correctly. In fact, I'm pretty sure it doesn't right now. Just for one obvious example, I believe a row-header should really be optional.

Comment: unfortunately thing like this:

cells: 
     | cells cell
     ;

cell: TD TEXT CLOSE_TD
    ;

doesn't work! :( and I have no idea how to make an empty rule work. I've even tried {$$=NULL;} no help.